# How to get PHP error messages via CURL

Tags: php, testing, curl

I'm writing a PHP CLI testing tool for large Websites. It checks the HTTP Response Code on Websites written in PHP. The tool works with cURL.
But if i get not the expected status code (expected should be 200, but I get 500), I don't know why. Is there a possibility to get the occurred error on the website via curl to save it in an Report or something else?

Comment: Not unless the php site outputs the errors into the document or headers, which is unusual for a production environment

Answer (score 0):

Try with get_headers() first before doing the actual cURL call.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the function curl_getinfo(). You can find the documentation here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

The procedure is as follows:

1. Prepare curl with curl_init and save the resulting handle in a variable
2. Send your request (as you know: if not successfull response is empty but no code)
3. Now call curl_getinfo with the handle from step one. You should get an associative array containing all needed values for your purpose. The return code you are looking for is in the index "http_code". curl_info always fetches the data of the last request upon a handle.

Hope this helps!